# How can you get details about crash of Android app?

Tags: android, crash

It is not really a programming question. I have this app that continues to crash on my phone, but works fine for everybody else. I used to program android apps, so I have knowledge in this field.

It something on my phone probably it always crashes at the same stage. I did not program this app. How can I still get the details of the error or the trace of the exception?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest plugging the phone into your computer or laptop, opening up the `Logcat` tab in *Android Studio* and viewing the exception details as the app crashes.

This can be done separately from *Android Studio* using ADB but it involves more steps.

Of course, make sure that you have enabled USB debugging on your device before this.

[image]